# Issues with Binary Tree Pruning implementation in Python

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm currently working on LeetCode problem 814, "Binary Tree Pruning," and I've encountered some difficulties with my implementation. The problem requires returning a modified binary tree where every subtree not containing a value of 1 has been removed.

Here's my initial code:

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def pruneTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if root is None:
            return None

        self.pruneTree(root.left)
        self.pruneTree(root.right)

        if root.val == 0 and root.left is None and root.right is None:
            root = None
            return 

        return root
```

Unfortunately, my implementation did not produce the expected results and caused errors. However, when I consulted with others, they suggested the following code, which works correctly:

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def pruneTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if root is None:
            return None

        root.left = self.pruneTree(root.left)
        root.right = self.pruneTree(root.right)

        if root.val == 0 and root.left is None and root.right is None:
            root = None
            return 

        return root
```

I'm having trouble understanding why my initial solution, which doesn't utilize the `root.left` and `root.right` variables, didn't work as expected, while the modified solution provided by others does. I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this and help me understand the underlying issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Publishing content generated by ChatGPT (not only answers) [isn't allowed currently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: In your code, you weren't modifying the branches - the `return` value was not used at all, it was just discarded. With new one, you actually say "in the current object, I want to change left to whatever recursion on left gives me and right to whatever recursion on right gives me". Also, the root = None does nothing, the point is the `return` without anything - which is equal to `return None`. `root` is just local variable there, only the returned value matters

Comment: You got a couple of answers. Any feedback on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you perform the recursive calls to self.pruneTree(root.left) and self.pruneTree(root.right), but you don't assign the return values back to the root.left and root.right!

```
def pruneTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
    if root is None:
        return None

    root.left = self.pruneTree(root.left)
    root.right = self.pruneTree(root.right)
```

The key difference is that the version above keeps track of the pruned subtrees by updating the left and right child pointers of the current node.

Answer (score 0):

As your code never assigns anything to an attribute, we can already be sure the tree will not change.

The assignment `root = None` will only set the value of a local name. It doesn't affect the tree; it doesn't change a `left` or `right` attribute. So doing:

```
    root = None
    return
```

Has no meaningful difference with just doing:

```
    return
```

About this aspect, see also [How do I pass a variable by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/5459839).